# Force implementing classes to use their own type as the type for a method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

I have an interface that a set of objects implement. I would like all objects in the set to implement a `MemberWiseCompare(ImplementingType rhs)` method which requires they use their own type as the argument type.

After a little research it seems that I could change my interface from something like;

```
  public interface IMyInterface
```

to

```
 public interface IMyInterface<T>
```

Then use `T` as the argument type for the `MemeberWiseCompare` method. However, I'm hoping there is an alternative solution because this produces something like 200 compiler errors and thus will require a lot of work to do. Also I think it could cause some problems because there are places where I use `IMyInterface` as a return or argument type and I'm sure changing all of those to the generic version would complicate the code. Is there an alternative way of doing this? Are there any better options?

Comment: Generics is the way to go.

Comment: There's the "curiously recurring template pattern," [except it's not particularly enforceable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) in C#. But give it a review just the same. As for your existing methods returning the now non-generic interface, you can keep this version as the base for the generic version and code that does not *need* the generic can still work.

Comment: What sort of compiler errors?
Would doing `public interface IMyInterface<T>:IMyInterface` as an intermediary step help?

Comment: Isn't that where [F-bounded polymorphism](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) would be useful? If so, it's unfortunately unavailable in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your interface currently looks like:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool MemberwiseCompare(object other);
}
```

in which case you could change it to:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool MemberwiseCompare<T>(T other) where T : IMyInterface;
}
```

This keeps the interface non-generic, but gives you some extra type safety when passing invoking `MemberwiseCompare`. The implementations shouldn't need to change (apart from their signatures) since they currently will have to do a runtime type check anyway. I assume most of the call sites won't need to change either due to type inference on generic parameters.

EDIT: Another possibility is that you could add the generic `IMyInterface<T>` interface, and have your implementing classes implement both interfaces (one will need to be implemented explicitly). Then you could gradually move over to the generic interface while obsoleting the non-generic version e.g.

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface, IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public bool MemberwiseCompare(MyClass other) { ... }
    bool IMyInterface.MemberwiseCompare(object other)
    {
        MyClass mc = other as MyClass;
        return mc != null && this.MemberwiseCompare(mc);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is more in line with what I would like. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit longer to see if there are any other good suggestions, but I doubt I'll find something more suitable.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal This is probably the path I would take as well